# Running php in apache cordova?

Tags: cordova

Folks !

I am developing an app hybrid with apache cordova and I need to run php. Testing on the virtual host works fine (no trick). But when I try to run the cordova run browser it does not load the data coming from the database (php + mysql)? Is it because of the cordova server not running php ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a server-side language like PHP in a client-side framework like cordova. You have to use javascript (or typescript) to implement the hybrid part of your application and you can use Java (Android) or Obj-C (iOS) to add native functionality.